# what is file * in stdio.c souce file in glibc that has & operator

Tags: glibc

```
#include "stdio.h"

#undef stdin
#undef stdout
#undef stderr
FILE *stdin = (FILE *) &_IO_2_1_stdin_;
FILE *stdout = (FILE *) &_IO_2_1_stdout_;
FILE *stderr = (FILE *) &_IO_2_1_stderr_;
```

What do these file * lines mean in the stdio.c file in glibc source code, what does the & operator mean in the last three lines. what is *IO_2_1_stdin*, is it a file or what does & operator mean in that line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` are the standard streams required by the spec. These are their definitions. Each points to a matching implementation-defined structure - in this case, those structures are global variables named `_IO_2_1_stdin_`, etc. The `&` is the normal address-of operator.

Comment: And the whole construct is necessary because `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` should *only* be defined if `<stdio.h>` has been included.